# Will Intel Core i7-870 support Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

My question is will Android Studio work with Intel Core i7-870?

I have red the minimum system requirements and it looks like its good, but this processor is back from September 2009 and its the only thing I have right now.

Thank you.

Comment: I would say, give it a go ;) I think you won't have any problem with that.

Comment: It's very likely, but you would be best served upgrading your machine when you get a chance to anyway.  Not just because that processor is over six years old, but also due to the fact that you're surely limited by more critical infrastructure, like memory.

Comment: As long as you can run the required operating system it should run with no problems.

Comment: You're probably bound to the requirements of Java, which is *"Both the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) and Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) require at minimum a Pentium 2 266 MHz processor."* [src](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_system_requirements.html#BABBGHIH). So yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rquirements :

```
Windows :
Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
2 GB of available disk space minimum,
4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android
  SDK and emulator system image)
1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
Java Development Kit (JDK) 8
For accelerated emulator: 64-bit operating system and Intel® processor with 
support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit 
functionality
```

you can see more on this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=CjwKEAjw4dm6BRCQhtzl6Z6N4i0SJADFPu1nzk4CBXAJksB3kQ4Q8YMajJzNF6FYkLckzdm4CpmqohoC_0Pw_wcB